# Call stored procedure in Symfony2 and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, symfony

How to call stored procedure in Symfony2?

I created a stored procedure in PostgreSQL named `get_manhours_all()` which returns the result of this:

```
select
    sum(
        extract(epoch from end_time) - extract(epoch from begin_time)
    )/3600 as manhours
from timeslot;
```

Is there a method in Symfony2 to call `get_manhours_all()` - the native query is `SELECT get_manhours_all();`.

Comment: I presume you're using the default ORM, Doctrine? You can use the calls in that, or use a raw PostgreSQL call - the PHP manual is sure to have an example. Although you're using Symfony, remember you're just using PHP - so the question really is "How do I call a PostgreSQL procedure in _PHP_?".

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Symfony 2 method to call your SP as it's stored in your database. You should make such a call using [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) as follow,

```
$conn      = $this->get('database_connection');
$statement = $conn->executeQuery('/*SQL Call to your stored procedure*/');
$results   = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: yeah, that's clean method.. but in my case, i've got an error like this: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion..."

Comment: @AsepFajarNugraha,it probably means that on a backend you are binding the array to the frontend variable, which expected to be a string, so no problem with query. I suppose that you should try to use not the `$results` but the `$results[0]` or something like this. You'd better see, what `$results` holds.